# Getting a number from the string and using it to replace the text in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a certain string in my row of my text file, such as this:

```
<img title="\frac{3}{8}" src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\dpi{50}&amp;space;\fn_phv&amp;space;\frac{3}{8}" alt="" />
```

Basically it contains a html code for a fraction. But now I would like to replace it with:

```
<sup>3</sup>&frasl;<sub>8</sub>
```

So it should take the word "\frac{3}{8}" and replace it accordingly for each line. The word "\frac{3}{8}" will also change accordingly.

I know I need to use regular expressions but need guidance to do this.

My code:

```
with open('/Users/cnnlakshmen/Downloads/qz_question.sql', 'r') as fin:
    filedata = fin.read()

filedata1 = re.sub(r'<img\b[^<]*(?<=title=")\\frac\{(\d+)\}\{(\d+)\}"[^<]*>', "<sup>\g<1></sup>&frasl;<sub>\g<2></sub>", filedata)
print filedata1

# Write the file out again
with open('/Users/cnnlakshmen/Downloads/qz_question1.sql', 'w') as fin:
  fin.write(filedata1)
```

Comment: Not usre what you want: to replace the whole `img` tag to `<sup>1-st-NUMBER</sup>&frasl;<sub>2nd-NUMBER</sub>`? Or just the `\frac{3}{8}` must get replaced with `<sup>3</sup>&frasl;<sub>8</sub>`?

Comment: replace the whole string. to replace the whole img tag to <sup>1-st-NUMBER</sup>&frasl;<sub>2nd-NUMBER</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the numbers are positive integers

`pattern = '\\frac\{(\d+)\}\{(\d+)\}'`

Or for postive/negative, integers and decimals

`pattern = '\\frac\{(-?\d+\.?[\d?]*)\}'`

`replaceWith: '<sup>\1</sup>&frasl;<sub>\2</sub>'`

```
import re
regex = re.compile(pattern)
re.sub(regex, replaceWith, inputString)
```

Comment: first of all, thanks. I have two qns. How do I assign it back to the variable that contains all the lines of data? Secondly, each line of text filecontains different data. I need to check whether test_str exists in the line before I start on changing it. How do I do it?

Comment: I can't remember off the top of my head, I think it's `inputString = re.sub(replaceWith,inputString)` or possibly that re.sub changed the contents of input string, just test to find out. To check if the string exists use `re.match(inputString)`, it will return true or false if the match is successful.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the whole `img` tag using

```
<img\b[^<]*\btitle="\\frac\{(\d+)\}\{(\d+)\}"[^<]*>
```

And replacing with

```
<sup>\1</sup>&frasl;<sub>\2</sub>
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yC0gP2/2)

[IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/Mb0A1U):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'<img\b[^<]*\btitle="\\frac\{(\d+)\}\{(\d+)\}"[^<]*>')
test_str = "<img title=\"\\frac{3}{8}\" src=\"http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\dpi{50}&amp;space;\\fn_phv&amp;space;\\frac{3}{8}\" alt=\"\" />"
subst = "<sup>\g<1></sup>&frasl;<sub>\g<2></sub>"
print re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

Comment: first of all, thanks. I have two qns. How do I assign it back to the variable that contains all the lines of data? Secondly, each line of text filecontains different data. I need to check whether test_str exists in the line before I start on changing it. How do I do it?

Comment: It is a substitution, just run the regex against the entire string. You do not have to check if the string contains the img tag, the line won't get changed if match is not found. Well, a good idea is to post some code of yours to see what is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: i will post my code, do look at it and comment. Posted it already.

Comment: Just replace your 2nd paragraph with `line = re.sub(r'<img\b[^<]*(?<=title=")\\frac\{(\d+)\}\{(\d+)\}"[^<]*>', "<sup>\g<1></sup>&frasl;<sub>\g<2></sub>", line)`. You are not changing `line`, mind that in Python these variables are immutable.

Comment: then how to change the line so it can be stored in filedata.

Comment: Replace the `filedata`, not `line`, or create a new variable and append lines to it after each `line` replacement. I think I meant to suggest `filedata = re.sub(r'<img\b[^<]*(?<=title=")\\frac\{(\d+)\}\{(\d+)\}"[^<]*>', "<sup>\g<1></sup>&frasl;<sub>\g<2></sub>", filedata).` Sorry for confusion. The regex is quite safe to run against large texts I believe.

Comment: so don't need to go line by line? edited the code in the qn.

Comment: It looks good to me now, except that you do not have to print `print filedata1`. :) It was just for demo purposes.

Comment: but when i look at qz_question1.txt, it contains the unwanted string. don't know what's my mistake.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81661/discussion-between-lakesh-and-stribizhev).

Comment: I still have issues with this. Need some help on this. do msg me. Thanks.