# How to change the string with new string in a whole file in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have asked this question:[Getting a number from the string and using it to replace the text in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31075019/getting-a-number-from-the-string-and-using-it-to-replace-the-text-in-python/31075160?noredirect=1#comment50169491_31075160) earlier. But I still face an issue. I need to change the string with the new string in the whole file, but I am not able to do it. When I print out the data or write it to a new file, I am not able to see the change take effect. Not sure what is the issue.

This is what I tried first:

```
with open('/Users/lakesh/Downloads/qz_question.txt', 'r') as fin:
    filedata = fin.read()

filedata1 = re.sub(r'<img\b[^<]*(?<=title=")\\frac\{(\d+)\}\{(\d+)\}"[^<]*>', "<sup>\g<1></sup>&frasl;<sub>\g<2></sub>", filedata)
print filedata1

# Write the file out again
with open('/Users/lakesh/Downloads/qz_question1.txt', 'w') as fin:
  fin.write(filedata1)
```

I have assigned replaced word to another variable, but the new variable still has the same string, it doesn't seem replaced. I have tried to replace with the filename. I have also tried to replace line by line as well:

```
for line in filedata:
    re.sub(r'<img\b[^<]*(?<=title=")\\frac\{(\d+)\}\{(\d+)\}"[^<]*>', "<sup>\g<1></sup>&frasl;<sub>\g<2></sub>", line)

print filedata
```

qz_question1.txt still contains the img tag. It doesn't seem to be replaced. Need some guidance on this.

qz_question has huge text, one of the lines look like this:

```
(163, 'S001', 'T005', 'ST015', 'Medium', '1', 9, '1', '<p>The ratio of the number of children to the number of adults at a funfair was 2 : 5.​&nbsp;&nbsp;<sup>1</sup>&frasl;<sub>5</sub>of the children were boys. If there were 120 more adults than children, how many girls were there at the funfair?</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>', 'without_image', '[{"value":"16","answer":"0"},{"value":"40","answer":"0"},{"value":"64","answer":"1"},{"value":"120","answer":"0"}]', '<p>5 -2 = 3</p>\n<p>3 units --&gt; 120</p>\n<p>1 unit --&gt; 120 &divide; 3 = 40</p>\n<p>2 units --&gt; 40 x 2 = 80</p>\n<p>1 - <img title="\\small \\frac{1}{5}" src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\\small&amp;space;\\frac{1}{5}" alt="" width="5" height="20" />&nbsp;=&nbsp;<img title="\\small \\frac{4}{5}" src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\\small&amp;space;\\frac{4}{5}" alt="" width="4" height="16" /></p>\n<p><img title="\\small \\frac{4}{5}" src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\\small&amp;space;\\frac{4}{5}" alt="" width="4" height="16" />&nbsp;x 80 = 64</p>', 'lakshmen K', NULL, '1', '0', '2015-05-03 15:54:19', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
```

Comment: Is this a new question, or another question on top of the first question?

Comment: separate qns, but the questions are linked. i want to show what I have tried so far

Comment: @lakesh , can you post content of  `qz_question.txt` ?

Answer (score 0):

What about using replace?

If you can paste a copy of the file along with what you're wanting to transpose the string to, I will correct my `replace`'s

```
with open('/Users/lakesh/Downloads/qz_question.txt', 'r') as fin:
    filedata = fin.readlines()

for line in filedata:
    line.replace('<img', '<sup')
    line.replace('</img>', '</sup>')
```

Then either overwrite or save to a new file.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see the problem is in the regexp because before \frac there is \small.
Instead the code syntax python is correct.
You can check this:

```
import re
str = '<img title="\\small \\frac{4}{5}" src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\\small&amp;space;\\frac{4}{5}" alt="" width="4" height="16" />'
p = re.compile('img\b[^<]*(?<=title=")\\frac\{(\d+)\}\{(\d+)\}"[^<]*>')
print p.match(str)
```

return **None**